# Subclassing QGraphicsLayoutItem to display a pixmap

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I was trying to have a QGraphicsPixmapItem into a QGraphicsLinearLayout.
Since that is not possible, because QGraphicsPixmapItem is not a QGraphicsLayoutItem, 
I am trying to subclass the latter, and make it work like a pixmap item.

Here's my failing attempt:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyItem(QtGui.QGraphicsLayoutItem):
  def __init__(self, image, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.gitem = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
    self.gitem.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(image))

  def sizeHint(which, constraint, other):
    return QtCore.QSizeF(200, 200)

  def setGeometry(self, rect):
    self.gitem.setPos(rect.topLeft())

  def graphicsItem(self):
    #does not get called
    return self.gitem

def setGraphicsItem(self, item):
    self.gitem = item

class Application(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    gwidget = QtGui.QGraphicsWidget()
    layout = QtGui.QGraphicsLinearLayout()
    layout.addItem(MyItem(r'C:\image1.jpg'))
    layout.addItem(MyItem(r'C:\image2.jpg'))
    gwidget.setLayout(layout)
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    scene.addItem(gwidget)
    self.setScene(scene)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Application()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And as evident from the comment, the graphicsItem() method does not get called, and I
end up with a super-white milky graphics view.

How do I achieve this, dear Qt scientists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graphicsItem` is not virtual. That's why Qt doesn't call it. It seems you need to call `setGraphicsItem` in your constructor and remove `graphicsItem` and `setGraphicsItem` methods from your class. Reimplementing non-virtual functions doesn't make any sense.

Comment: And how is calling **setGraphicsItem** from the constuctor going to change anything?. How does the system know about the item the class is representing if not calling **graphicsItem**?. Is there special magic I should do in **setGraphicsItem**?.

Comment: The system calls default implementation of `graphicsItem()` which returns an item that was previously set using default implementation of `setGraphicsItem`. Just call `self.setGraphicsItem(self.gitem)`.

Comment: Okay. I just removed `setGraphicsItem` and `graphicsItem` and did what you said and it seems to work. Thanks a lot.